# Dealing with errors when trying to CONCAT a string and <f0 string> struct in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have code below:

```
DECLARE vector ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE table_name STRING;
SET vector = ["AA","AB","AC"];

FOR loop_variable_name IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(vector))
DO
  SET table_name = CONCAT('mergingtask.preclean.linkedin', loop_variable_name);
  CREATE TABLE `', table_name, '` 
  AS SELECT * FROM `mergingtask.preclean.preclean_data_sorted` WHERE last2 = loop_variable_name;
END FOR;
```

and the error information is:

> Query error: No matching signature for function CONCAT for argument types: STRING, STRUCT<f0_ STRING>. Supported signatures: CONCAT(STRING, [STRING, ...]); CONCAT(BYTES, [BYTES, ...]) at [32:20]

It seems that the system treat loop_variable_name as type STRUCT<f0_STRING> but I want it to be recognized as STRING (so that I can use CONCAT).

I try to CAST but it failed. The error is:

> Query error: Invalid cast from STRUCT<f0_ STRING> to STRING at [32:65]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try like so, should do the trick…

```
DECLARE vector ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE table_name STRING;
SET vector = ["AA","AB","AC"];

FOR loop_variable_name IN (SELECT vectorElmnt FROM UNNEST(vector) vectorElmnt)
DO
  SET table_name = CONCAT('mergingtask.preclean.linkedin', loop_variable_name.vectorElmnt);
  CREATE TABLE `', table_name, '` 
  AS SELECT * FROM `mergingtask.preclean.preclean_data_sorted` WHERE last2 = loop_variable_name.vectorElmnt;
END FOR;
```

Let me know if it does NOT work

Cheers!